# Can you query a HANA analytical view as if it's the orginal table?

Tags: sql, cube, hana

Suppose you have a HANA analytical view, but you have no access to the table that was the origin of the analytical view.

The analytical view has pre-aggregated columns, but you need the columns without the pre-aggregation, otherwise the query will get the wrong result.

For example if there are the integer columns Price and Profit, and your query has SELECT SUM(PRICE*PROFIT). With the regular table on each row there would be a PRICE*PROFIT calculation, and then the result would aggregate that to SUM(PRICE*PROFIT) from each row. But with the analytical view's pre-aggregation, you end up getting SUM(PRICE)*SUM(PROFIT), which is not the same as SUM(PRICE*PROFIT).

Yes, if there's another column with a unique value per row, that can be added to the query, and you can get multiple rows from the analytical view that will aggregate as I need. And you can do a SELECT * to get all rows without pre-aggregation, but that doesn't allow including the SUM(PRICE*PROFIT).

In my case, my program has no idea which columns would have the unique value to do the aggregated calculation correctly.

Is there any way to query an analytical view as if it was its original table?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution: do a `SELECT *` as a subquery, then you have the original table to query from:

```
SELECT "State", SUM("Price" * "Profit") AS PxP FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM AVTable
)
GROUP BY "State"
```

Comment: What do you mean by `AVTable` in your answer?

Comment: AVTable is the name of your Analytical View